# Postgres upsert avoid 2nd unique constraint?

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint, upsert

I have a table of the form (based on):

```sql
create table foo (
  name text unique,
  ref_id int,
  mod_time timestamptz
);
```

I would like to be able to insert into it, but
instead updating `mod_time` if (`name`, `ref_id`) pair was in use, and failing if `name` were in use for another `ref_id`.

I can do this by creating another unique constraint as follows:

```
alter table foo add unique (name, ref_id);
```

Then

```
insert into foo values ( $1, $2, $3 )
on conflict (name, ref_id) do update set
  mod_time = excluded.mod_time;
```

will function as I want:

- If new name, inserts
- If same name and ref_id, changes mod_time
- If same name for different ref_id, fails

However, the cost is a 2nd unique index, which is in fact superfluous for enforcing the constraint as records unique by `name` will automatically be unique by `name` and `ref_id`.
Is there some workaround that will get me this behavior without the 2nd index, and without additional roundtrips to the database?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by fail.  If it's okay to just not do anything in this case: `where If same name for different ref_id` you could do the following:

```
insert into foo values ($1, $2, $3)
on conflict (name) DO update set
mod_time = excluded.mod_time
WHERE foo.ref_id = excluded.ref_id;
```

You could check how many rows were modified after running the query and raise an exception if none were modified.

Comment: Thanks! hmm... I did think of the where clause, but forgot I could check the # of rows modified. I'll accept as answered if no one comes up with anything better in a few days.